# jQuery DateBox receives continuous mousedown

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, datebox

I'm using the [TimeBox plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) and facing an issue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Mousedown on decrease(-) or increase(+) buttons of a field.
2. While holding the mouse button down, move outside the button.
3. Release the mouse button.

Result: The related field receives a continuous event and keeps changing the hour/minutes/am-pm.

I could do the same on the author's site and it's reproducible on TimeBox and DateBox.

The real issue is that I'm using it on a mobile app where a user can scroll and if the user happens to scroll somewhere on the DateBox, it shows the above behaviour. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that has gone through a couple of iterations to try and meld the preferred behavior with he reality of how to do it - long story short, you can turn off "repButton" to get rid of the repeat function.

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/api/repButton/